# Why hyperlinks lost after merging PDF files using mPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, hyperlink, pdf-generation, mpdf

I have to merge some pdf files with hyperlinks inside. Merging with mPDF is fine, but there are no hyperlinks in output file! There are text only left.

```
require_once('./mpdf/mpdf.php');

$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', '8', '', 10, 10, 7, 7, 10, 10);
$mpdf->SetImportUse();

$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile('./static_files/01_file.pdf');
$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage(1);
$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
$mpdf->WriteHTML();

$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile('02_SourceFile.pdf');
for ($i=1;$i<$pagecount;$i++) {
    $mpdf->AddPage();
    $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);
    $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML();
}

$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile('./static_files/03_file.pdf');
for ($i=1;$i<=$pagecount;$i++) {
    $mpdf->AddPage();
    $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);
    $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML();
}

$mpdf->Output('Output.pdf', '', 'F');
```

Files 01_file.pdf, 03_file.pdf are static (it miens they was created using desktop tools like Acrobat or LibreOffice) and 02_SourceFile.pdf was created by tcpdf. All three files by they own contain pages with active hyperlinks but after merging there are no active hyperlinks left, only the caption text for each one.

What is wrong? Or how to merge pdf files using other PHP tool (it is important to use only cross-platform tools and preferred PHP).

Comment: I found a script that is implements links support to FPDI, wich is used in mPDF wich is best solution on PHP I found for now. Here it is: [link](https://gist.github.com/andreyvit/2020422#file-fpdi_with_annots-php) Now I'm researching how to make it work together with mPDF, so any kind of help needed.

Comment: I know this is pretty old but in case somebody needs it, what you need is create a new file in the root of your mPDF installation, call it what you want.
In it include  the file mpdf.php once and copy the class FPDI_with_annots from the link provided above (https://gist.github.com/andreyvit/2020422#file-fpdi_with_annots-php) 
Modify the class so it extends mPDF instead of FPDI.

Now when you want to use mpdf, call the newly created file and use the class fpdi_with_annots instead of mPDF. Use it as you would mPDF normally et voila, it works and yor links are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily merge PDFs with QPDF or PDFTK, which are both free tools. They're not PHP, but you can easily write a PHP wrapper for them and run in Linux.

I personally prefer QPDF as it is content-preserving and doesn't mess up any metatags, whereas PDFTK likes to set the author.

Have a look at [the QPDF site at sourceforge](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The main problem is that I developing on Linux a unit for windows based web server. mPDF was just fine but I can figure out why it kills hyperlinks.

Answer (score -1):

@user1173016

you need use `<=`

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$pagecount;$i++) {
```

instead of `<`

```
for ($i=1;$i<$pagecount;$i++) {
```

because you will loose first page in second case, and if `$pagecount = 1` you will import nothing.